# Extracting the last file name from a field where the number of folders and length of file names is variable

Tags: sql, string

I am trying to extract the last file name from a field in SQL where the separator is `/`, and there is also one after the last file name. (I am using this to create a new filed in a BI web intelligence document.)

`Filename1/filename2/filename3/filename4/` result required `Filename4`

`File1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6` result required `file6`

I have tried various combinations but without success. As you can see the file names are not of a standard length and the number of folders is variable.

Any help on this would really be appreciated.

Thank you

Lyn

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (The answer will probably be product specific!)

Comment: The two examples ... one has "/" at the end and the other one does not ?  Can you guarantee "/" at end or not ?

Comment: Generally speaking.... reverse the string and then get the first one.  Most databases have some sort of reverse function.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your answer to my comment ... do you have a input string that ends with "/" or not ?   I have put both types of test strings in this query using SQL 2008 as dbms. Just comment out either Set @tstString to run each condition and you will see the two result possibilities.

```
Declare @tmpFirstMark int
Declare @tmpLastMark int
Declare @tmpUseMark int

Declare @tstString varchar(100)
Set @tstString = 'Filename1/filename2/filename2/filename4/'
Set @tstString = 'File1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6'

-- Calculate 1st Occurrence of "/"
Set @tmpFirstMark = PATINDEX('%/%',@tstString)
-- Calculate last Occurrence of "/"
Set @tmpLastMark = (LEN(@tstString) - PATINDEX('%/%',REVERSE(@tstString)) + 1)
-- Calculate 2nd to last Occurrence of "/"
Set @tmpUseMark = @tmpLastMark - PATINDEX('%/%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@tstString, 1, @tmpLastMark-1)))

Select
    @tstString
    ,@tmpFirstMark
    ,@tmpLastMark
    ,@tmpUseMark

    ,SUBSTRING(@tstString, @tmpLastMark + 1, LEN(@tstString)) as 'resultSTR'
    ,SUBSTRING(@tstString, @tmpUseMark + 1, @tmpLastMark-@tmpUseMark-1) as 'otherResult'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to retrieve the desired output :

```
([^/]+)/?$
```

This will match as many non-`/` characters as possible (at least 1) before the end of the string, that may be followed by an optional `/`.
You will want to use the first group of the match to retrieve the filename of a directory without its trailing `/`.

You haven't specified your RDBMS and I'm not so confortable with using regexps in SQL so I hope you'll be able to piece that together in your SQL dialect.